# Why do I keep getting 'Expected Expression Pylance Error'?

Tags: python, vscode-debugger

keyboard, each out of 10 marks and use this data to determine the individual’s grade.
Grade bands:
A – 80 to 100
B – 70 to 79
C – 60 to 69
D – 50 to 59
F – below 50

I am a beginner to python and would like some advice on how to fix the errors in my code
[this is what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwPoh.png)

```
print ("Insert first grade")
g1=input("Enter input")

print ("Insert second grade")
g2=input("Enter input")

print ("Insert third grade")
g3=input("Enter input")

print ("Insert fourth grade")
g4=input("Enter input")

print ("Insert fifth grade")
g5=input("Enter input")

Sum = ([g1,g2,g3,g4,g5])
Total = 50

def Percentage(Sum, Total):
    return 100*Sum/Total

if (Percentage >= 80) and (Percentage <= 100):
    print ("Grade: A")
elif (Percentage >=70 and Percentage <= 79):
    print ("Grade: B")
elif( Percentage >= 60 and Percentage <= 69):
    print ("Grade: C")
elif (Percentage >= 50 and Percentage <= 59):
    print ("Grade: D")
else:
    print ("Grade: F")
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. If you included that code as **text** in your post (and you can edit it now to do so) then it would be much easier to help you as we could cut and paste and work with it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with this line:

```
Sum = ([g1,g2,g3,g4,g5])
```

That just creates a list of the grades; it doesn't add them up. If you want to add them together, you can use this:

```
Sum = g1+g2+g3+g4+g5
```

or this:

```
Sum = sum([g1,g2,g3,g4,g5])
```

As you can see from the above, Python has a built-in function named `sum` already, which means it's a bad name to use for your own variable. Letter case matters to Python, so `Sum` is distinct and technically fine, but it's actually considered good style to stick to lowercase for regular variables and functions, and only use uppercase for constant values and class names.

Indentation also matters, so this is an error:

```
def Percentage(Sum, Total):
return 100*Sum/Total
```

The `return` is the body of the function you're defining, so it needs to be indented further than the `def`:

```
def Percentage(Sum, Total):
    return 100*Sum/Total
```

And that creates a function that you need to call; you aren't calling it, but treating it as a number, which won't work.

Why is Total 50 when there are only 5 grades?

For that matter, why are you hard-coding the number of grades? You should just use a loop to read in as many as the user wants to input. Something like this, perhaps:

```
print ("Enter a negative number to end grade input")
grade = 0
count = 0
total = 0

while grade >= 0:
    grade = int(input("Enter next grade: "))
    if grade >= 0:
        total += grade
        count += 1
```

And then you can use your percentage function to calculate the rest (note that I used "total" for what you called "Sum", and "count" for what you called "Total").

Comment: Thanks! Your feedback has been really helpful and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of pointers:

**1) `Percentage()` is a function you want to call**

```py
def Percentage(Sum, Total):
    return 100 * Sum / Total
```

makes `Percentage()` a method/function that you want to call here to get the results not get the function. At the moment,

```py
if Percentage >= 70:
```

is testing if the function is greater than 70, not the result of calling the function which you would do with something like:

```py
if Percentage(Sum, Total) >= 70:
```

**2) Missing comparison on line 15 also `or` vs `and` (code as image)**

Your first set of comparisons are missing a value (likely 80) and uses `or` when you probably wanted `and`.

You have

```py
if Percentage >= or Percentage <= 100:
```

combined with point 1 about, you want:

```py
if Percentage(Sum, Total) >= 80 and Percentage(Sum, Total) <= 100:
```

or more compactly as:

```py
if 80 <= Percentage(Sum, Total) <= 100:
```

**3) `input()` returns a string that you want to do math on**

When you get `input()` from the user you get a string but you want to treat it as a number so you can do math on it.

rather than:

```py
g1 = input("enter grade")
```

you want something more like:

```py
g1 = float(input("enter grade"))
```

Now you can do math with `g1` as it is an number rather than a string.

**4) `Sum` is a `list` but you treat it as a individual number inside of `Percentage()`**

In your method, `Percentage()` you seem to want to pass in the full list of grades (as stored in `Sum`) and we can't do division on a list like that.

Perhaps `Percentage(Sum, Total)` could be written as:

```py
def Percentage(Sum, Total):
    return 100 * sum(Sum) / Total
```

Note now as well that `Total` seems to be based on the number of items in `Sum` and perhaps we could derive it when needed rather than hard coding it.

**Putting it all together (but keeping a light touch) you might think about:**

```py
def get_average_grade(grades):
    return 100 * sum(grades) / (len(grades) * 10)

g1 = float(input("Enter your first grade (out of 10): "))
g2 = float(input("Enter your second grade (out of 10): "))
## ...

grades = [
    g1,
    g2,
    #...
]

average_grade = get_average_grade(grades)

if 80 <= average_grade <= 100:
    print("Grade A")
else:
    print("Study more")
```

Comment: When using if 80 <= Percentage(Sum, Total) <= 100: the error I got was TypeError: Percentage() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: You are probably using the altered version of that function I offered later. Try just taking a copy of the final code block and test it. Then you can modify it to include additional courses